# how to toast ArrayList values

Tags: android, android-toast

How to toast values in this?

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

               params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mtd", "empLogin"));
               params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("request[cmp_id]", ""));
               params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("request[user_name]", username));
               params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("request[password]", password));
               params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("request[remember]", remember));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can toast each individually:

```
for (NameValuePair pair : params) {
    Toast.makeText(this, pair.getValue(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Or put them all in a string and post together:

```
String str = "";
for (NameValuePair pair : params) {
    str += pair.getValue() + ' ';
}

Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,params.get(0),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Where **params.get(Your Arraylist Index)**.

Hopes its works for you.